# Angular 5- Storing current route in variable *with id*

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using routing in Angular to pull the url and store it in a global variable. It works well, except for when the url has an 'id' in it.

For example, my Url == '/site/1' however....

```
 this.authService.current_route = this.router.url
 // '/site'  (not 'site/1' or 'site/:id')
```

How do I refactor to make this work?

My html looks like:

```
<span id="sitehead"> <a [routerLink]="['/site', site.id ]" (click)="changeroute()"> Site:</a></span>
```

My component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css'],

})
export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() site;

constructor(private _dataService: DataService, private http: Http, public authService: AuthService, private router:Router ) {

}

changeroute(){
  this.authService.current_route = this.router.url
  console.log(this.authService.current_route)

}
```

Thanks!! Let me know if I can clarify

Comment: is the route with an id a child of the main '/site' route?

Comment: this.route.snapshot.url

Comment: @bryan60 yes it is

Comment: Why exactly do you have a `routerLink` as well as a `(click)` handler? Isn't it redundant? Also, post your routeConfig if possible to better understand. I think you don't have a child route specified for `site/:id`

Comment: so the reason this isn't working doesnt have anything to do with the ID parameter, it has to do with how Angular's router scope operates. Basically, the router is scoped to the component where it is injected and it's structured like  a tree.  So the router injected at the child route would see the full route, but injected at the parent route, it sees it's currently scope segment and has children, you can recurse through the children though to get the full path.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a less complicated way to get the current url, but in the past, I created a function that does it. Hopefully it suits your immediate needs.

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    const path = this.getPath(route.snapshot);
}

private getPath(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
    const urlSegments = route.pathFromRoot.map(r => r.url);

    return '/' + urlSegments.filter(segment => !!segment && segment.length).join('/');
}
```